# Papers in Math Journals that Turn Out to be Sophisticated Versions of Simpler Facts

Tags: proof-explanation, publishing

I'm interested in a list of papers in Math Journals that were celebrated as new discovery but turn out to be sophisticated versions of simpler facts. A brief explanation of the simpler version of the math concept would also be helpful.

For example, [Rowland's prime generating sequence](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/JIS/VOL11/Rowland/rowland21.pdf) turns out to be equivalent to

> Given $n\geq2, n\in\mathbb{N}$, the first differences plus 1 of the iteration $f(n) = n + lpf – 1$ is always prime, where lpf means the least prime factor of n. Start with $n=2$ we get $2\to3\to5\to9\to11\to21\to23\to45\to47\to93\to95\to99\to101...$

The above is always true for the simple reason that we keep adding "$lpf - 1$" to the previous term to get the next term. By definition lpf is prime.

Comment: check this out http://johncanning.net/wp/?p=1863

Comment: some researcher claims to have invented the trapezoid rule for numerical integration

Answer (score 1):

Check this out johncanning.net/wp/?p=1863

Mary M. Tai, a Diabetes Researcher devised a "brand-new" method to accurately calculate the area under graphs numerically. Little did she know that her "new" discovery was actually the trapezoid rule, a method for numerical integration known for hundreds of years.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer does not address the question. Tai's paper was not published in a mathematical journal, and I would not describe her ''results'' as a sophisticated version of a simpler fact, since there is nothing sophisticated in her presentation of the trapezoidal rule that would obscure it from being recognized by the mathematically literate.